# Formulas of synthetic polymers

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have a question regarding synthetics. $\ce{(C8H8)}_n$ is the formula for polystyrene. What exactly does the $n$ stand for?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

*n* is the number of molecular units in a chain, also called the [degree of polymerization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_polymerization). This varies based on the molecular weight of the polymer. The molecular weight is the degree of polymerization times the molecular weight of a monomer.